# How do I call a .Net Module function from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

This code generates an assembly. The Assembly has a single static method, called "Test2", that outputs "Wow!" to teh command line. This method isn't in a class - it's a "global method" on the assemblies module.

```
     var fileName = "output_name.dll";
     var assemblyName = "MyAssembly";
     var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
     var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName, fileName);
     var testMethod2 = module.DefineGlobalMethod("Test2", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), null);
     var generator2 = testMethod2.GetILGenerator();
     generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Wow!");
     generator2.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }), null);
     generator2.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
     module.CreateGlobalFunctions();
     assembly.Save(fileName);
```

Now that I have the method, I'd like to reference the assembly from C# and call the method. But since the method isn't in a class or a namespace, I'm not sure how to do this.

Does C# have a way to call global methods like this without using reflection?

Comment: Not really. Read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx